# similarity measure scikit-learn document classification

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am doing some work in document classification with scikit-learn. For this purpose, I represent my documents in a tf-idf matrix and feed a Random Forest classifier with this information, works perfectly well. I was just wondering which similarity measure is used by the classifier (cosine, euclidean, etc.) and how I can change it. Haven't found any parameters or informatin in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most supervised learning algorithms, Random Forest Classifiers do not use a similarity measure, they work directly on the feature supplied to them. So decision trees are built based on the terms in your tf-idf vectors.

If you want to use similarity then you will have to compute a similarity matrix for your documents and use this as your features.